# Algorithm with Scrypt and PBKDF2 - Python

Tags: python, cryptography, python-2.x, pbkdf2, scrypt

I have tried to reproduce this algorithm on Python

(Double pipes mean to add 0x1 or 0x2 to the passphrase)

```
s1 = scrypt(key=(passphrase||0x1), salt=(salt||0x1), N=2^18, r=8, p=1, dkLen=32)

s2 = pbkdf2(key=(passphrase||0x2), salt=(salt||0x2), c=2^16, dkLen=32, prf=HMAC_SHA256)

keypair = generate_bitcoin_keypair(s1 ⊕ s2)
```

And I made this:

```
s1 = pyscrypt.hash(password=phrase+'\x01', salt=saltPhrase+'\x01', N=16, r=8, p=1, dkLen=32)

s2 = pbkdf2(phrase+'\x02', saltPhrase+'\x02', 1, keylen=32, prf='hmac-sha256')

newWallet = BitcoinKeypair.from_passphrase(''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s1,s2)))
```

The problem is that it doesn't work properly because it generates this

```
bitcoin address: 1HvAip4QGWqPJoh8nxLmRAXtbuVj9AKGHq

Wif: 5Kd3D34oALv33x7RMAPrrsNtidZjQekdWHXWGXW6cs2SnRkKUR2
```

but the correct output is this:

```
bitcoin address: 1MGKWPZEqJh9JzCPYYsKFEo9w8E2GXmzA7

Wif: 5KXwsERJKvUZde3qHboJFz1gF6B15Xt7TB22bRWoGzgN3FHxqyR
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Here there's the entire code: http://pastebin.com/QL0tQ83v

---

To use this script you need to install these libraries:

```
pip install pyscrypt passlib coinkit
```

Comment: please explain how it does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an implementation of [WarpWallet](https://keybase.io/warp), which is where I guess you are getting your “correct” values. You have two issues.

Firstly `BitcoinKeypair.from_passphrase` generates a key from a passphrase, but you have already generated the key yourself, so you don’t need this—you can just use the key you have (you’ll need to import `binascii` to use `hexlify`):

```
# xor the two subkeys as before.
key = ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s1,s2))
# Convert to a hex string first (coinkit / pybitcoin expects hex
# rather than raw bytes).
key_hex = hexlify(key)
# Create the keypair.
newWallet = BitcoinKeypair(key_hex)
```

(Also `BitcoinKeypair` appears to be deprecated now, perhaps you should look into moving to pybitcoin and `BitcoinPrivateKey` and `BitcoinPublicKey`).

Secondly your work factors in both kdfs are way off. For scrypt it should be 2^18 (you have 16) and for pbkdf2 it should be 2^16 (you have 1).

Here’s a version that gives the same result as the WarpWallet page (note I am using `scrypt` here rather than `pyscrypt`, as `pyscrypt` wanted to eat my laptop’s entire memory when I fixed the iteration count):

```
s1 = scrypt.hash(password=phrase+'\x01', salt=saltPhrase+'\x01', N=1<<18, r=8, p=1, buflen=32)
s2 = pbkdf2(phrase+'\x02', saltPhrase+'\x02', 1<<16, keylen=32, prf='hmac-sha256')

key = ''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s1,s2))
key_hex = hexlify(key)
newWallet = BitcoinKeypair(key_hex)
```